# Detectar fichero MP4 corrupto en JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, video

Tengo un servidor hecho en node, que me genera un video. A la hora de llamar a la URL si las imágenes proporcionadas son capaces de generar un video responde un código 200 y genera el video en segundo plano (si no es capaz de generarlo devuelve un 500 y no genera el video en segundo plano).

Por otro lado tengo otra dirección la cual me responde tres respuestas en base al fichero que estaba generando en segundo plano. Si está creado devuelve {"message":"true"}, si no existe {"message":"false"}, y si existe, pero está corrupto (es decir, el video aun sé esta genrando) devuelve {"message":"pending"}

```
    try {
        var stats = fs.statSync(videoFolderPath + "video.mp4")
        var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
        console.log("Video size: " + fileSizeInBytes); // TODO: Devuelve simepre true este corrupto o no FIX
        if (fileSizeInBytes <= 0) {
            res.status(200).json({ exists: "processing" })
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ exists: "true" })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(200).json({ exists: "false" })
    }
```

Me falta por tratar el caso de que el fichero este corrupto. Ya que ahora valoro su peso. pero a medida que se genera el fichero tiene peso, existe pero no esta terminada su generacion.Me devuelve true cuando deberia de devolver pending.

¿Como podria detectar que un fichero .mp4 esta corrupto o no?

Gracias de antemano

**EDIT**

```
try {
    fs.statSync(videoFolderPath + "video.mp4") //Valida que existe el cihero
    try {
        console.log(videoFolderPath + "video.mp4");
        fs.readFileSync(videoFolderPath + "video.mp4");//Deberia de fallar en caso de que el fichero este corrupto, pero no falla y me devuelve true
        res.status(200).json({ exists: "true" })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(200).json({ exists: "processing" })
    }
} catch (err) {
    res.status(200).json({ exists: "false" })
}
```